# Why is my Queue always empty?

Tags: c#, multithreading, amazon-ec2, tcp, queue

I am using Amazon AWS to develop a small application. I am using a client/server architecture. When I run both the client and server applications on the same instance, I have no issues, but when I deploy the server application to another instance, I have trouble. I have opened all required ports and sorted out firwalls, etc. There is no communications issue between the Client instance and the Server instance: messages between the client to the server arrive perfectly, without issue.

My issue is that on my Client application, a queue, which is populated in another class on another thread, is always empty when running over the network.

My "CommunicationsManager" on the client application looks like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Hazel;
using System;
using Hazel.Tcp;
using System.Net;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

public class CommunicationsManager
{

    //public  Queue RawMessages = Queue.Synchronized(new Queue()); //Doesn't work either
    public Queue<byte[]> RawMessages = new Queue<byte[]>();

    public int Port;
    public bool RunLocally;
    public TcpConnection Connection { get; set; }

    public CommunicationsManager(int port)
    {
        Port = port;
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        var ip = RunLocally ? "127.0.0.1" : "SOME REMOTE IP";
        NetworkEndPoint endPoint = new NetworkEndPoint(ip, Port);
        Connection = new TcpConnection(endPoint);
        Connection.DataReceived += DataReceived;
        Connection.Connect();
    }

    private void DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        //This does fire and it does add to RawMessages
        RawMessages.Enqueue(args.Bytes);
        args.Recycle();
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        if (Connection.State == ConnectionState.Connected)
        {
            Connection.Close();
        }
    }

    public void Send()
    {
        //Not implemented
    }

}
```

I have another class called "Client" and this object checks to see if a message has arrived and if so, dequeues and processes it.

```
using Hazel;
using Hazel.Tcp;
using NLog;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Client
{

    private CommunicationsManager CommunicationsManager;

    void Start()
    {
        CommunicationsManager = new CommunicationsManager();
        CommunicationsManager.RunLocally = RunLocally;
        CommunicationsManager.Port = Port;
        CommunicationsManager.Connect();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (CommunicationsManager.RawMessages.Count > 0)
                {
                    // Always zero...
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.Debug("No message from server...");
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

For some reason, my `CommunicationsManager.RawMessages.Count` is always zero. I've tried using `ConcurrentBag`, `ConcurrentQueue`, I've tried having a thread read this queue (in the CommunicationsManager class) and populate another queue and have the `Client` read from that new queue, but nothing seems to work.

Messages are definitely arriving... the `DataReceived` event does fire and the `RawMessages` queue does contain data.

The strangest thing is that this DOES work when the client and server applications are the the same machine... if I move the server application to another instance, it does not work.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: So how do you know that messages are arriving and queue is not empty if count is always zero?

Comment: @Evk I can debug in the `CommunicationsManager.DataReceived` function.

Comment: Then you can put breakpoints on both `RawMessages.Enqueue(args.Bytes);` and `CommunicationsManager.RawMessages.Count > 0` and inspect how it goes.